# Luna JBoss Tools JBoss 7.1 AS - server is always in "starting" state

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x, jboss-tools

Could any one guide me on how to debug this issue?

The server always says "Starting". Then, since the timeout is set to 720 seconds, once 720 seconds are reached, the server shuts down automatically.

Even though the status of the server says as always starting, our application that is deployed functionally works fine.

In J2EE perspective, Eclipse does not give any warning, JBoss just shuts down. In Java perspective, it gives the following error. Error details:

```
Plugin:org.eclipse.wst.server.core

Severity:Error

Server JBoss AS 7.1 was unable to start within 720 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Exception Stack Trace: An exception stack trace is not available.

Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_76
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments: -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clean -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

After this, the next error is as shown below:

```
org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core
The server was shutdown forcefully. All processes were terminated.
```

I do not know if there is any log file that I can look into to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you no longer have this problem, but if it can help to someone, here is how I got to solve this issue after try a bunch of stuff.

This problem certainly means that eclipse is not able to monitor the jboss server, and that’s why eclipse thinks that jboss doesn’t start, so that increase very long the timeout is useless.

first make sure about the following:

The port used by jboss (in server.xml for jboss AS or standalone.xml for Jboss EAP) is the same than the monitored by eclipse in jboss server configuration pane ( by double clicking on the server in servers view -> Server Ports section -> Web).
If you are using a standard port like 8080, you can try changing it, for instance to 8180.

If you have checked the above points, the last thing you can try (and what worked for me) is changing the host name through the eclipse jboss config pane, from localhost to 127.0.0.1

[image]

Hope this solve the problem!